# Flex column with equal height items with adaptive img height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want make 100% height page. Items should always be equal height. I dont know **how many items will be in column**. If item contain img, img should fill 100% height of item.

**Example for two item:**

**now:**
[image]

**what need:**
[image]

sandbox:
https://codepen.io/krosert/pen/eYJVzMK

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="imgWrap">
     text....
  </div>
   <div class="imgWrap blue">
     <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e2/a9/68/e2a968e625554f72e8673945be1daa33.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

body,html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.root{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.imgWrap{
  background-color: #832;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

img{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: remove flex-shrink:0 and use min-height:0

Answer (score 1):

In order to have no scroll, you can use `overflow: hidden;` property, if it fits the case. Also, for the columns, you can use a `flex` container, containing divs that have min-height and width, and no padding. Inside of each div you would have an image with height and width: 100%.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, nothing to do with the code, but I would go for a cleaner design. There is a lot of text and if you put more images this would just get worse, becoming terrible to read. Try making a longer page or putting less content, if it's possible.